# Jar file trying to install a bundle saved on its classpath shows "Cannot Find The File Specified"

Tags: java, file, jar, osgi, bundle

In my code, I am embedding Apache Felix, and install a bundle as the following:

```
Bundle AB= adereContext.installBundle("file:ADEREBundle_1.0.0.201402211848.jar");
AB.start();
```

The bundle "ADEREBundle_1.0.0.201402211848.jar" is saved on the project directory, and so I assume that this should work.

Now, when I run this code in a normal java application, it shows no error, and the bundle is successfully installed.

However, when I jar my whole project (including the code above), and try to use it in another java application, it shows:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to cache bundle: file:ADEREBundle_1.0.0.201402211848.jar
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2870)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:165)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:138)
    at aderetest.Main.main(Main.java:40)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ADEREBundle_1.0.0.201402211848.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:70)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:161)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.getURLConnectionInputStream(SecureAction.java:524)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.JarRevision.initialize(JarRevision.java:165)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.JarRevision.<init>(JarRevision.java:77)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleArchive.createRevisionFromLocation(BundleArchive.java:878)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleArchive.reviseInternal(BundleArchive.java:550)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleArchive.<init>(BundleArchive.java:153)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleCache.create(BundleCache.java:277)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2866)
```

What is so special about the case of jaring my project, and which made my bundle file not seen? The bundle is for sure on the root directory of the jar, and I can see it.

How can I solve my problem? Thanks.

**Note:** having the bundle outside my jar file, and using its full-path to install it works, but I want it to be inside my jar.

Comment: Try having the ADEREBundle_1.0.0.201402211848.jar outside your project in classpath

Comment: This works, but i want it inside.

Comment: AFAIK,I don't think you can't do install it, since it is wrapped inside an artifact. Why don't you have it seperate since you need to get it installed anyway

Comment: My jar will be given to developers who do not have the same path as mine. So keeping the bundle outside the jar file means its path will be dependent on the machine path which is ugly.

Comment: Give them as two jars where both should be placed in the same location. i think this will help

Comment: and what would be the path of the jar bundle in this case?

Comment: I got it now. It will be same path, except that the bundle is outside the jar file. Thank you.

Comment: By default, Jvm will look for the jar in the current directory

Comment: I will post this as my answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK,I don't think you can do install it directly, since it is wrapped inside an artifact. Why don't you have it separate since you need to get it installed anyway.Give them as two jars where both should be placed in the same location. i think this will help. By default, `JVM` will look for the jar in the current directory

Answer (score 0):

You can try this declaring your dependencies in the `Manifest.mf` file:

```
Class-path: dependency1.jar dependency2.jar
```

See more here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html